# select a file under a directory?

Tags: bash

In bash, when being under a directory, how can we select a file or subdirectory without actually typing its name or even part of its name?

Is there a way to enumerate or alternate the files or subdirectories, such as  how we can use TAB to switch between several things in a webpage?

Does it depends on the application to open the file or subdirectory?

If yes,

- how can we select a subdirectory among several subdirectories for `cd`?
- how can we select a pdf file from several pdf files for `evince`?

E.g.

```
$ ls .
  subdir1 subdir2
$ cd
```

Can we choose `subdir2` for `cd`, without typing `subdir2` or any part of it? Ideally it will be good to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to select and alternate between `subdir1` and `subdir2`, so we can stop at `subdir2` and then hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Comment: I have literally *no idea* what it is that you are asking...

Comment: It is perfectly normal. Don't blame yourself too much ...

Answer (score 4):

Set

```
bind TAB:menu-complete
```

and then run `evince`<kbd>TAB</kbd>. Hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> multiple times to go through different files.

Comment: Thanks. TAB is also used for autocompletion of command names among others. Will making this binding change the original functions of TAB?

Comment: I found that after running your bind command, TAB doesn't list all possible completions any more, but just alternate between the options. Can we have both?

Comment: I doubt that you can bind one key to two different functions. But you can bind one of the command to different key, e.g. `Shift-Tab`. BTW, there are more possible completion functions, you can read about all of them in the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html

Comment: Is this `bind` command set for the current non-login shell only? or for all the shells?

Comment: Only for current shell. If you want to use it permanently you need to modify `.bashrc` or other bash dot file (probably `.inputrc` would be the better choice in this case).

Comment: BTW, there is enhanced bash-completion project developed and supported by debian: http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/ and if you would switch to `zsh` then there is **huge** spectrum of possible completion systems, with basic menu style: `zstyle ':completion:*' menu select`, but that's probably not what you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Files can be enumerated with

```
for file in .* * do;
  # if targeted at files:
  test -f "$file" || continue
  # if targeted at directories:
  test -d "$file" || continue
  # in both cases arises the question: What about symlinks?
done
```

or (to save the time for sorting) with

```
ls --quoting-style=escape | while IFS= read file; do...
  : check type like above
done

find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -printf %f\\n | while IFS= read -r file; do...

find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -printf %f\\n | while IFS= read -r file; do...
```

(The `find` variant does not handle strange file names.)

Comment: thanks. but how can you select a subdirectory for `cd`?